# YII login don't show me menu items

Tags: php, cookies, yii

I have a problem with my yii application which is:

- There are types of users that can log into my application, each will be shown some items in the menu.
- When I log in not using the remember me checkbox I don't see the items I should see in the menu (I think it doesn't create a session for user and user role).
- But when I log in with the checkbox checked, I see the items in the menu (I have enabled Cookie based authentication to check this).

How can I get the user to see his items when he/she logs in without having them to check the *Remember me* checkbox?

This is my authentication code

```
<?php

/**
 * UserIdentity represents the data needed to identity a user.
 * It contains the authentication method that checks if the provided
 * data can identity the user.
 */
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
/**
 * Authenticates a user.
 * The example implementation makes sure if the username and password
 * are both 'demo'.
 * In practical applications, this should be changed to authenticate
 * against some persistent user identity storage (e.g. database).
 * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
 */
private $_id;
public function authenticate()
{
    $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
    if($user === null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    elseif($user->password!== sha1($this->password))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else{
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        $this->setState ('role', $user->role);
        $this->_id = $user->id;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
}
```

This is my action login

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

and this is the LoginForm login

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

And this is the menu code

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'Volunteers', 'url'=>array('/volunteers/index'),
             'visible'=>((!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) && 
             (Yii::app()->user->role==='admin' 
             || Yii::app()->user->role==='DataEntry' 
             || Yii::app()->user->role==='CCGazb'))
             ),
             array('label'=>'Create Volunteer', 'url'=>array('/volunteers/create'),
             'visible'=>((!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) && 
             (Yii::app()->user->role==='Interviewer'))
             ),
            array('label'=>'Interviews', 'url'=>array('/interviews/index'),
             'visible'=>((!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) && 
             (Yii::app()->user->role==='admin' 
             || Yii::app()->user->role==='Interviewer' 
             || Yii::app()->user->role==='CCGazb'))
             ),
             array('label'=>'Teachers', 'url'=>array('/teachers/index'),
             'visible'=>((!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) &&
             (Yii::app()->user->role==='admin' 
              || Yii::app()->user->role==='Interviewer' 
              || Yii::app()->user->role==='CCTeachers' 
              || Yii::app()->user->role==='Trainer'))
             ),
            array('label'=>'Users', 'url'=>array('/user/index'),
             'visible'=>((!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) && 
             (Yii::app()->user->role==='admin'))
             ),
            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    )); ?>
</div><!-- mainmenu -->
```

Comment: Always include your code in the question! Post your menu code! What conditional statement are you using to check if it's a logged-in user?

Comment: I posted all code related.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session in action like :

```
public function actionLogin() {
    // If the user is already logged in send them to the return Url 
    if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        $this->redirect(Yum::module()->returnUrl);

    $this->layout = Yum::module()->loginLayout;
    $this->loginForm = new YumUserLogin('login');

    $success = false;
    $action = 'login';
    $login_type = null;
    if (isset($_POST['YumUserLogin'])) {
        $this->loginForm->attributes = $_POST['YumUserLogin'];
        $t = Yum::module()->loginType;

        // validate user input for the rest of login methods
        if ($this->loginForm->validate()) {
            if ($t & UserModule::LOGIN_BY_USERNAME) {
                $success = $this->loginByUsername();
                if ($success)
                    $login_type = 'username';
            }
            if ($t & UserModule::LOGIN_BY_EMAIL && !$success) {
                $success = $this->loginByEmail();
                if ($success)
                    $login_type = 'email';
            }                          
        }  
        //cookie with login type for later flow control in app
          if ($success instanceof YumUser) {
             if ($login_type) {
                $cookie = new CHttpCookie('login_type', serialize($login_type));
                $cookie->expire = time() + (3600 * 24 * 30);
                Yii::app()->request->cookies['login_type'] = $cookie;
            }
            Yum::log(Yum::t(
                            'User {username} successfully logged in (Ip: {ip})', array(
                        '{ip}' => Yii::app()->request->getUserHostAddress(),
                        '{username}' => $success->username)));
            if (Yum::module()->afterLogin !== false)
                call_user_func(Yum::module()->afterLogin);

            $this->redirectUser($success);
        } else
        //  $this->loginForm->addError('username',Yum::t('Login is not possible with the given credentials'));
            $this->loginForm->addError('username', Yum::t(''));
    }


    $this->render(Yum::module()->loginView, array(
        'model' => $this->loginForm));
}
```